# Button command keeps updating when it should be static

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a calculator but I'm having trouble when I'm trying to make buttons appear progressively as you add more numbers to memory, however the commands I give the buttons to clear and recall the memory don't function properly because they keep updating to the last number of the memory.

I tried to give the commands of the buttons a number in a list so it would delete the correct number but instead it keeps updating to the last. here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import *
import re
import keyboard
import customtkinter as ctk

expression = "0"
memcc = 0

def numbersel(num):
    global expression
    if num == 0 and expression == ('0'):
        pass

    elif expression == ("0"):
        expression = ""
        expression = expression + str(num)
        equation.set(expression)

    else:
        
        expression = expression + str(num)
        equation.set(expression)

def equalsel():
    try:
        global expression

        total = str(eval(expression))
        equation.set(total)
        expression = total
    
    except:
        
        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""

def clearsel():
    global expression
    expression = "0"
    equation.set("0")

def memstore():
    global expression
    global memcc
    
    if expression[len(expression)-1] == "+" or expression[len(expression)-1] == "-" or expression[len(expression)-1] == "*" or expression[len(expression)-1] == "/":
        equation.set(" ERROR ")
        
    elif "+" in expression or "-" in expression or "*" in expression or "/" in expression:
        strVarLst.append(tk.StringVar())
        strVarLst[memcc].set(eval(expression))
        Memct.append(tk.StringVar())
        MemR.append(None)
        MemR[memcc]= ctk.CTkButton(memfr, text="MR", width=10, height=4, command=lambda:memcall(Memct[memcc - 1]))
        MemR[memcc].grid(column = 0, row = memcc)
        MemC.append(None)
        MemC[memcc] = ctk.CTkButton(memfr, text="MC", width=10, height=4, command=lambda:memclr(Memct[memcc - 1]))
        MemC[memcc].grid(column = 2, row = memcc)
        Memlabels.append(None)
        Memlabels[memcc] = ctk.CTkLabel(memfr, textvariable=strVarLst[memcc], width=20, height=4)
        Memlabels[memcc].grid(column = 1, row = memcc)
        memcc = memcc + 1  
        
    else:
        strVarLst.append(tk.StringVar())
        strVarLst[memcc].set(expression)
        Memct.append(memcc)
        MemR.append(None)
        MemR[memcc]= ctk.CTkButton(memfr, text="MR", width=10, height=4, command=lambda:memcall(memcc - 1))
        MemR[memcc].grid(column = 0, row = memcc)
        MemC.append(None)
        MemC[memcc] = ctk.CTkButton(memfr, text="MC", width=10, height=4, command=lambda:memclr(memcc -  1))
        MemC[memcc].grid(column = 2, row = memcc)
        Memlabels.append(None)
        print("HELLO?")
        print(Memlabels)
        Memlabels[memcc] = ctk.CTkLabel(memfr, textvariable=strVarLst[memcc], width=20, height=4)
        Memlabels[memcc].grid(column = 1, row = memcc)
        memcc = memcc + 1  

def memcall(MemR):
    global expression
    if strVarLst[MemR].get() == "":
        pass

    elif expression=="0":
        print("success")
        expression = str(strVarLst[MemR].get())
        equation.set(expression)

    elif re.search(r'\d+$', expression):
        print("NO")

    else:
        print("success")
        expression = expression + str(strVarLst[MemR].get())
        equation.set(expression)

def memclr(MemCl):
    global memcc
    print(Memct)
    print(memcc)
    print(MemCl)
    if strVarLst[MemCl] == "":
        print("dont")

    else:
        strVarLst[MemCl].set("")
        strVarLst.pop(MemCl)
        Memlabels.pop(MemCl)
        MemR[MemCl].destroy()
        MemC[MemCl].destroy()
        
        for x in range(MemCl, Memct[-1]):
            if Memlabels[x] == None:
                pass
            else:
                strVarLst[x].set(strVarLst[x].get())
                Memlabels[x].grid(column= 1, row=x)
        Memct.pop(MemCl)
        memcc = memcc - 1
        
window = ctk.CTk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.rowconfigure(0,minsize=50, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0,minsize=50, weight=1)



strVarLst = []
Memlabels = []
MemR = []
MemC = []
Memct = []
equation = tk.StringVar()
equation.set("0")
memcc = 0
mainfr = ctk.CTkFrame(window, width= 20, height= 10)
mainfr.grid(column = 0,row = 0, sticky='nwes')
mainfr.rowconfigure([0,1,2,3,4,5],minsize=50, weight=1)
mainfr.columnconfigure([0,1,2,3],minsize=50, weight=1)
expression_field = ctk.CTkEntry(mainfr, textvariable=equation, width=300)
expression_field.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
btn0 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=0, width=210, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(0))
btn0.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, column=0,sticky = 'news')
btn1 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=1, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(1))
btn1.grid(row=4, column=0,sticky='nwes')
btn2 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=2, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(2))
btn2.grid(row=4, column=1,sticky='nwes')
btn3 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=3, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(3))
btn3.grid(row=4, column=2,sticky='nwes')
btn4 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=4, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(4))
btn4.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky='nwes')
btn5 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=5, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(5))
btn5.grid(row=3, column=1,sticky = 'nsew')
btn6 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=6, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(6))
btn6.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky = 'nsew')
btn7 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=7, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(7))
btn7.grid(row=2, column=0,sticky = 'nsew')
btn8 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=8, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(8))
btn8.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky = 'nsew')
btn9 = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=9, width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel(9))
btn9.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky = 'nsew')
btndiv = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="/", width=50, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel("/"))
btndiv.grid(row=1, column=3,sticky = 'nsew')
btnmul = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="*", width=50, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel("*"))
btnmul.grid(row=2, column=3,sticky = 'nsew')
btnmin = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="-", width=50, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel("-"))
btnmin.grid(row=3, column=3,sticky = 'nsew')
btnpos = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="+", width=50, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel("+"))
btnpos.grid(row=4, column=3,sticky = 'nsew')
btnequ = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="=", width=50, height=40, command=equalsel)
btnequ.grid(row=5, column=3,sticky = 'nsew')
btndot = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text=".", width=100, height=40, command=lambda: numbersel("."))
btndot.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky = 'nwes')
btnclr = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="CLR", width=100, height=40,command=clearsel)
btnclr.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky = 'nsew')
mems = ctk.CTkButton(mainfr, text="MS", width=100, height=40, command=memstore)
mems.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky = 'nsew')
memfr = ctk.CTkFrame(window,width=250,height=750)
memfr.grid(column=1,row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
memfr.rowconfigure([0,1,2],weight=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the behaviour you are experiencing is a [for-a-beginner-rather-cryptic-behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) of lambda functions in combination with "non-local" variables:

The memcc variable is accessed when the lambda is called — not when it is defined. Hence, it will always use the last value.

To avoid this behaviour, you can make memcc local for lambda by introducing a local variable with memcc as default value:

```py
command=lambda i=memcc: memcall(Memct[i - 1]),
#[...]
command=lambda i=memcc: memclr(Memct[i - 1]),
#[...]
command=lambda i=memcc: memcall(i - 1),
#[...]
command=lambda i=memcc: memclr(i - 1),
#[...]
```

This will not make the desired functionality fully work (there seems to be an "[off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)" index error somewhere), but at least gets rid of the main issue.